# Possible to get 'regex source' from match?

Tags: javascript, regex

I can get the source of a regex when it's defined separately. For example:

```js
let r1 = new RegExp("el*");
console.log(r1.source);
// el*
```

Or:

```js
let r2 = /el*/;
console.log(r2.source);
// el*
```

Is there a way to extract that if the regex isn't defined separately? For example, something along the lines of:

```
let m = "Hello".match(/el*/);
console.log(m.source?);
```

Comment: `source` is a compiled regex object property, match data object does not contain any reference to the pattern itself.

Comment: There might be a way to examine the match object in other languages in more detail. Did you expect to get specific stuff like group info and start /end positions etc .. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,

quoting the [documents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) of the match() function

> Return value
>
> An Array whose contents depend on the presence or absence of the
> global (g) flag, or null if no matches are found.

So the return value is an array (you can test it by `Array.isArray(m)// true`)

However, the returned array has some extra information about the ocurred match (like groups, index and original input) but none of them include the original regex used to get the match

So there is no way to get that information from the match because its not returned by the matching function

Comment: I am downvoting this answer because the only thing relevant to the question is the last line, which contains no evidence or argument. I am also perplexed how the OP could have found this useful, much less awarded it a green checkmark.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your downvote. However I dont understand your point. What do you mean by "no evidence or argument"? I quoted and linked MDN documentation and provide a simple way to test. Arrays are just containers. Just by the datatype you can assure that the information you are looking for is not there.

Comment: The OP wants to know if he can determine what regex was used when there is a match. Your argument could equally conclude that the string index where the match begins cannot be determined, but it can (`str.match(/.../).index`).

Comment: Ahhh I see your point. Yes, you are right, the fact that the return value is an array is not enough to conclude that there is not extra data relating the match. I pointed to the documentation but did not mention that part. Thanks for pointing that out, Ive added that clarification to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The match result by itself cannot lead to the original regex, simply because different regexes can lead to the same result, even on the same string. Take for example the string `"abcd"` - all the following regexes: `/abcd/`, `/a..d/` `/a.*/` and many more, would match the string exactly the same way.

The only way you could retrive the original regex is if a reference to the regex was literally stored by the `match()` method inside the returned object. There is no reason to think that's the case, but you can implement your own match function that would do. Something like

```
function myMatch(str, regex) {
  var match = str.match(regex);
  if (match === null) {
    match = [null];
  }
  match.source = regex;
  return match;
}
```

Comment: One obviously cannot reverse-engineer a string `s` to obtain the regular expression that produced it from a given original string, but that's not because multiple regular expressions could have produced `s`; it's because it is simply too difficult to compute *any* regular expression that would produce `s`. On the other hand, the language designers could have stored the argument `regex` in `match = str.match(regex)` with the match object, `match`, and provided a way of getting it from `match`. In effect, the question is asking whether they did.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, seeing your comments o  the other answer, I was careful and said "there is no reason to think that's the case" (that it is stored). Though in the case of a returned `null` value there is obviously nowhere to store the regex. The OP asked if there is a way to exract it, this way or another. Given a string and a match, I don't think it is that difficult to compute a possible regex, though I may be wrong. But I stand by may word that it is simply impossible because there is more than one possible answer.

Comment: Not that hard? You must have an Enigma machine for regular expressions! OK, here is your challenge. You are given the string `"str = "Humpty Dumpty had a great fall. Some say he didn't fall, that he jumped."`. I constructed a regular expression `rgx` such that `str.gsub(rgx, '') #=> "Hmpty Dmpty hd a grat fal. Som say h didn't fall, that he jumpd."`. Your assignment is to produce any value for `rgx` that produces the string that is returned. If you can do so, think how much harder it would be to do that with parsing code that you write for arbitrary pairs of strings. :-)

Comment: @CarySwoveland your challenge is not equivalent to reversing a match because you are requiring replacing a match by `''`. What about `str.gsub(/(H)u(mpty D)u(mpty h)a(d a gr)e(at fal)l(. Som)e( say h)e( didn't fall, that he jump)e(d.)/), '$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9')` ?

Comment: A+ on the match. I am proved wrong, and you could take a similar approach if a collection of matches were returned rather that the string resulting for replacing matches with empty strings. However, my main point, which is in my first comment beginning, "On the other hand....", remains. The time has come for me to begin a sleep cycle, so I will say, good night, even if the mid-day sun is above you at this moment.